# Java - Properties: Add new keys to properties file in run time?

Tags: java, properties, runtime, key, addition

Is it possible to create a new properties file and add keys and values in run time?
I want to add new keys to properties file depending on user input while installing my application. I checked out Java Properties class but it seem it can set values to existing keys but can not add new keys to properties file.

Comment: Also see [a better class to update property files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/565932/a-better-class-to-update-property-files)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can add new properties just by calling `setProperty` with a key which doesn't currently exist. That will only do it in memory though - you'll have to call `store` again to reflect the changes back to a file:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.load(...); // FileInputStream or whatever

prop.setProperty("newKey", "newValue");
prop.store(...); // FileOutputStream or whatever
```

Comment: Its not reflecting even i store the property changed,  any idea?

Comment: @PremanandK: I'm afraid I don't understand your comment at all. Perhaps you should ask a new question with a [mcve].

Comment: I saved my property changes as "prop.store(...);", but its not reflecting. ie. i am not seeing my changes in my properties file. Thanks for replying @Jon Skeet

Comment: @PremanandK: Again, ask a new question with a [mcve] so we can reproduce it. I certainly can't tell what's wrong from a one sentence description.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38797349/property-files-changes-not-reflected-after-storing-in-java - raised as the question.