# Add new entry to Java resource bundle from code

Tags: java, addition, resourcebundle

Im using Java resource bundles to localize my application and I have created a function which returns a message localized according to a resource bundle from a code... something like this:

```
public String getDescription(String code, ResourceBundle resBundle){
    String returnValue = null;  
    try{
        returnValue=resBundle.getString(code);
    }catch(Exception ex){
        returnValue = null;
    }
}
```

But, what I want to know if it is possible to add an entry to the resource bundle in case the code passed doesn't exist there, something like:

```
if(!resBundle.containsKey(code)){
    //This next line is pseudo-code... it is not valid at all
    resBundle.addEntry(code, "xyz");
}
```

Any help?

Comment: `ResourceBundles` a are not really designed to be changed from code. The idea behind them is to provide a static map of codes to localized values. Can you explain why you want to add an entry to the resource bundle? Perhaps there is a different approach to solving your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use `Properties` class and populate it by converting the ResourceBundle's keys to a `Stream` class, since Properties class functions like a `Map` with keys and values. For example :

```
Properties props = new Properties();
    resBundle.keySet().stream().forEach(k -> props.put(k, resBundle.getString(k)));
```

and then you can use the `getProperty()` method of `Properties` which returns the value you specify in the second argument in cases it doesn't find the key specified (in your case the key is `code`):

```
returnValue=props.getProperty(code,"xyz");
```

Comment: I don't understand your solution... it doesn't update the resource bundle with the key. I mean, what I need is to update the resource bundle adding the new key

Comment: I thought you could use a default value at runtime in cases you didn't find the key..Anyway i don't think you can modify values from `ResourceBundle `itself, it is used only for reading. But you can do it through `Properties` class, as mentioned : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571045/java-properties-add-new-keys-to-properties-file-in-run-time

Comment: Thank you Elton... I wanted a way to track which entries were not in the resource, so I could, periodically, see which entries I had to update.
What I have done is, with your method, have a parallel file were I save the entries not found.

Comment: Very well Pep.. If you find my answer helpful, please accept it. Thanks :)