# How to get specific key and set its value in java.util.ResourceBundle?

Tags: java, resourcebundle

Tried using methods: `getKeys()`, which returns `Set<>` and `keySet()`, which returns `Enumeration<>`, but i am not able to set value of specific key afterwards.

Comment: You are not supposed to change a ResourceBundle at runtime.  ResourceBundles are not for configuration, they are for providing text and other program data that can vary by locale.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct me if I am wrong but I think you can only read from resources bundle, to write you have to use Properties..
This might help you :- [Java - Properties: Add new keys to properties file in run time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571045/java-properties-add-new-keys-to-properties-file-in-run-time)